# Using AJAX & Json vs Action Method in MVC

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

What is the differences between using `AJAX` and `JSON` instead of Action Methods for `CRUD` operations (`Select`, `Insert`, `Update` and `Delete`) in `MVC`? For example in case using file upload operations, `AJAX` might be a problem. On the other hand, using `jQuery`, `AJAX` and `JSON` instead of standard `MVC` methods helps to improve responsiveness of the pages i.e. confirmation after create and update operations. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- In standard MVC action methods there is a PostBack but when you use AJAX the PostBack happens in the background so your application is more responsive and has a feeling of an app.
- In action methods it's very simple to implement `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to prevent cross-site request forgery attacks.When using AJAX you need to write a little function to achieve the same result(many people don't do this, resulting in a security vulnerability).
- Having a lot of javascript in a page can have a negative effect on page load times.Many companies, like Twitter, decided to switch back to server side rendering for that exact reason.[Article for reference](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/improving-performance-on-twittercom).
- When using AJAX you might run into accessibility issues, ofcourse jQuery minimizes a risk of that happenening but you still might experience problems with older browsers and mobile devices.With action methods(server side) you don't have that issue.

Comment: Many thanks for your perfect explanations. At this point: **1)** Could you please add an example code to your answer regarding to @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in AJAX call? **2)** If I implement anti forgery token in AJAX methods and use the javascript libraries in _Layout page or at the bottom of the page, can I solve the 2nd and 3rd points? **3)** For the 4th point we assume that all of our users use the latest versions of the browsers, but no idea why may it be problem in mobile devices. Could you please explain a little bit more the last point? Thanks...

Comment: Just do some research on google, you will literally find hundreds of articles on each one of the 4 points I've listed

Comment: What about the 3rd issue in my previous comment?

Comment: It's possible that your web application gets accessed by a mobile device with a very old browser then there's a possibility that your ajax call may not work.But like I said if you use jQuery the probability of that happening is very slim

Comment: Ok, thanks and voted+